# NPM advance-element/moment-with-locales.min.js

Tags: npm

Estou com problema no Laravel-mix com isso

WARNING  Compiled with 1 warnings                                                                                                                                         20:53:09

This relative module was not found:

- ./locale in ./resources/assets/pages/advance-elements/moment-with-locales.min.js
                                                                              Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
  images/vendor/datedropper/css/dd-icon/dd-icon.svg?92ba9af80fd03d0fa6671d1557c871a0    1.78 kB          [emitted]
                             fonts/themify9f24.eot?2c454669bdf3aebf32a1bd8ac1e0d2d6    78.7 kB          [emitted]
                            fonts/themify9f24.woff?a1ecc3b826d01251edddf29c3e4e1e97    56.1 kB          [emitted]
                             fonts/themify9f24.ttf?e23a7dcaefbde4e74e263247aa42ecd7    78.6 kB          [emitted]
                             fonts/themify9f24.svg?9c8e96ecc7fa01e6ebcd196495ed2db5     234 kB          [emitted]
  fonts/vendor/datedropper/css/dd-icon/dd-icon.eot?dedadb487a0539d3a4dbdba5edb07fe9    2.02 kB          [emitted]
  fonts/vendor/datedropper/css/dd-icon/dd-icond41d.eot?dedadb487a0539d3a4dbdba5edb07fe9    2.02 kB          [emitted]
  fonts/vendor/datedropper/css/dd-icon/dd-icon.woff?08bf52b3bbaf74a1e40c963c1ca78654     1.4 kB          [emitted]
  fonts/vendor/datedropper/css/dd-icon/dd-icon.ttf?b3fadd59b04db9316c75d82b7694f3be    1.86 kB          [emitted]
                             fonts/themifyd41d.eot?2c454669bdf3aebf32a1bd8ac1e0d2d6    78.7 kB          [emitted]
                               images/throbber.gif?65741b78f605e4d22eb4ad9570552c92    1.49 kB          [emitted]
                           images/details_open.png?ed1324976fd1dcb0d747a7ca5fc3ccc7  709 bytes          [emitted]
                          images/details_close.png?cdb0ad00d71eff5be6ca7305cff83ce9  686 bytes          [emitted]
                                     images/bg.jpg?dc3cf87d18112a35f6204913825585d4     142 kB          [emitted]
                                images/chat-bg.jpg?b04e814510747fb82cb17f2d2d86ad3a    64.8 kB          [emitted]
                               images/complete.png?f49f5eefa47626e63221e0fc1238af64     5.9 kB          [emitted]
                                                                         /js/app.js    5.34 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  /js/app
                                                                       /css/app.css     937 kB       0  [emitted]  [big]  /js/app

WARNING in ./resources/assets/pages/advance-elements/moment-with-locales.min.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './locale' in '/var/www/html/sistemas/frweb/crm/resources/assets/pages/advance-elements'
 @ ./resources/assets/pages/advance-elements/moment-with-locales.min.js 463:20-44
 @ ./resources/js/depedencies.js
 @ ./resources/js/app.js
 @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss

Alguém já passou por isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução mais simples para forçar o webpack a não gerar esse erro é forçá-lo a carregar algo diferente. Isso funcionou para mim:

Instale módulo vazio dessa forma:

> npm install --save-dev empty-module

E então configure ContextReplacementPlugin assim:

> new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(/./locale$/, 'empty-module', false, /js$/)

Espero que isso ajude.